# How to call classes in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new in GWT. I am facing following problem.
When ever I calling my UserDAO class into GWt main (entry point) it is giving me the following error that **Plugin fail to connect to Development mode server**. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This links will help you more

[Debugging a GWT application in a remote environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910472/debugging-a-gwt-application-in-a-remote-environment)

http://notepad2.blogspot.in/2010/12/debug-google-web-toolkit-applications.html